# Excel - Find Text Within a String in a Range

Tags: excel, find

I am hoping I can do this in Excel because I have not played with VBA for about 15 years.

I am trying to rebuild a client email list and for some reason a bunch of email addresses have duplicated themselves and then chopped letters off the front of the duplicated address.  I need to remove all the duplicates

e.g. of what I have is.

> Robert@email.com
>  Kimberly@othermail.com
>   James@anothermail.com
>  Michael@milmail.com
>   Julia@supermail.com

*and then underneath all of the good email addresses are the chopped off duplicates like this*

> ert@email.com
>  y@othermail.com
>  hael@milmail.com

Everything is in one column - A:A

I need a way to find all of the chopped off duplicates so that I can remove them.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Also I forgot to mention there are about 5,000 rows.

Comment: So the "chopped off duplicates" are all "underneath all of the good email addresses"? So, with that layout, what's the issue?

Comment: They are only underneath because I sorted them by the number of characters.  There are still genuine email addresses with short strings. Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And what logic dictates whether a given email is a "chopped-off" one or not?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in `A2:A5000` you can use the following formula in B2 and fill down:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$5000,"*" & A2)
```

Then you can autofilter values higher than 1 to find possible duplicates. You should be careful and check if some valid addresses are not a part of other valid positions (e.g. `Robert@email.com` and `JohnRobert@email.com`

Comment: That did tell me if an email address has a duplicate which is great.  Thanks for that.  There are over 3,000 duplicates though and as you point out not all are actual duplicates.  e.g.  There are a few Linda's, Melinda's, and Belinda's @ Gmail.com and they put their last name first.  e.g. joneslinda@gmail.com  smith.belinda@gmail.com.  Any ideas on a quick way to get through 3,000 duplicates with a formula?  Thanks so much.

Comment: @Dan  "Any ideas on a quick way to get through 3,000 duplicates with a formula?" Do you mean: is there a way to find only "chopped off duplicates"?, I can't think of any rule to distinguish valid and chopped positions.

Comment: Yes that is what I am saying.  Ideally I want to somehow say IF A2 is anywhere in A:A then add A2 next to each one that is found so that I can sort it.  The obvious problem with that is that when going down the list the results will all start overwriting themselves.